# How can unpack ZIPs using Gradle and add it to the sourceSets?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm migrating my Play framework project to use Gradle. I have a few Play modules which are ZIPped. While I've migrated most of my dependency management to Gradle, I'm a bit stuck with the ZIP dependencies. I have a folder called `mods` which in turn contains artifact directories containing the ZIP.

```
mods/
└── play-mockito/
    └── mockito-1.0.zip
```

I'd like iterate each of the directories in the `mods` folder and unpack the ZIP in that folder into another directory like so:

```
unpacked-mods/
└── play-mockito/
    └── Main.java
    ├── Test.java
    └── AnotherClass.java
```

Once unpacked I'd like to add the unpacked directory recursively to the sourceSets. I'm a bit lost with Gradle and now sure how to accomplish this.

---

Got so far:

```
task modulate << {
    def tree = fileTree('mods') {
        include '*/*.zip'
    }
    tree.each {File file ->
        def module = file.path.split('/')[-2]
        println "Unpacking " + module
        copy {
            from zipTree(file)
            into 'modules/' + module
        }
    }
}
compileJava.dependsOn(modulate)
```

Comment: Does the `modulate` task work well? Are zips unpacked? What's the problem then?

Comment: @Opal It seems to unpack it but I have not figured out how to add the extracted directories to the `java.srcDirs`